# Errors in generated parser "error: no declaration matches"

Tags: c++, g++, antlr, antlr4

This function in my C++ file is interacting with antlr:

```cpp
antlr4::tree::ParseTree* getTree(std::string caDefinition){
antlr4::ANTLRInputStream input(caDefinition);
CAsyntaxLexer lexer(&input);
antlr4::CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);

    tokens.fill();
    CAsyntaxParser parser(&tokens);
    auto tree = parser.prog();
    std::cout << tree->toStringTree(&parser) << std::endl << std::endl;
    return tree;
}
```

The syntax is defined as:

```
grammar CAsyntax;
prog: definition ';' rule ';';
definition: 'let' stateflag ':' NAME ',' COLOR
    | definition ';' definition;
stateflag: BOOLFLAG;
rule: rule ';' rule
    | stateflag '->' transition;
transition: state 'if' cond
    | state 'if' cond 'else' transition
    | '(' transition ')'
    | state;
cond: val COMPARISON val
    | cond OP cond
    | 'not' cond
    | '(' cond ')';
val: 'rand'
    | number
    | neighborhood '.' state;
number: INTEGER
    | REAL;
neighborhood: 'nm'
    | 'nv';
state: stateflag;

OP: '|' | '&' | '^';
COMPARISON: '>' | '<' | '=' | 'mod';
BOOLFLAG: 's'INTEGER;
COLOR: '#' [0-9a-f] [0-9a-f] [0-9a-f] [0-9a-f] [0-9a-f] [0-9a-f];
NAME: [a-zA-Z]+ ;
INTEGER: [0-9]+;
REAL: INTEGER '.' [0-9]+;
WS: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

The C++ files were generated with `antlr4 -Dlanguage=Cpp CAsyntax.g4`

I've tried a number of methods, including using the cmake method that antlr suggests.

I'm compiling my code with:

`g++ main.cpp grammar/*.cpp -lGL -lglfw -lGLEW -lpng -I/usr/include/antlr4-runtime -o automaton`

For some reason, doing `-lantlr4-runtime` instead of `-I/usr/include/antlr4-runtime` gives fatal errors about being unable to find "antlr4-runtime.h".

I am using antlr version 4.13.1-1

I was hoping it would give me a simple tree in string form to stdout, much like in the demo example which I compiled, and it worked (using cmake).

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:319:45: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
  319 |         HotShader computeShader = HotShader("compute.glsl");
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
grammar/CAsyntaxParser.cpp:157:30: error: no declaration matches ‘CAsyntaxParser::RuleContext* CAsyntaxParser::ProgContext::rule_()’
  157 | CAsyntaxParser::RuleContext* CAsyntaxParser::ProgContext::rule_() {
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from grammar/CAsyntaxListener.h:8,
                 from grammar/CAsyntaxParser.cpp:5:
grammar/CAsyntaxParser.h:59:18: note: candidate is: ‘antlr4::RuleContext* CAsyntaxParser::ProgContext::rule_()’
   59 |     RuleContext *rule_();
      |                  ^~~~~
grammar/CAsyntaxParser.h:54:10: note: ‘class CAsyntaxParser::ProgContext’ defined here
   54 |   class  ProgContext : public antlr4::ParserRuleContext {
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
grammar/CAsyntaxParser.cpp:1000:6: error: no declaration matches ‘bool CAsyntaxParser::sempred(RuleContext*, size_t, size_t)’
 1000 | bool CAsyntaxParser::sempred(RuleContext *context, size_t ruleIndex, size_t predicateIndex) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
grammar/CAsyntaxParser.h:202:8: note: candidate is: ‘virtual bool CAsyntaxParser::sempred(antlr4::RuleContext*, size_t, size_t)’
  202 |   bool sempred(antlr4::RuleContext *_localctx, size_t ruleIndex, size_t predicateIndex) override;
      |        ^~~~~~~
grammar/CAsyntaxParser.h:12:8: note: ‘class CAsyntaxParser’ defined here
   12 | class  CAsyntaxParser : public antlr4::Parser {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [makefile:8: build] Error 1
```

Comment: Post the complete and verbatim error message.

Comment: `-I/usr/include/antlr4-runtime` tells the compiler to include that absolute directory in the search path when looking for header files. If you specify `-Iantlr4-runtime` instead, that is a relative path and so the compiler expects to find the headers in that subdirectory under the _current working directory_ which happens to be where `main.cpp` lives in your case. So, is that where you installed this library? Probably not, right?

Comment: @paddy at no point am i using `-Iantlr4-runtime` i was hoping to use `-lantlr4-runtime` like i am using `-lGL`

Comment: @273K, done thanks, the error is with the generated code so idk

Comment: Your `g++` command is wrong. You forgot to include the generated headers in `grammar/`. In addition, you cannot name a parser rule as `rule`. It causes a "symbol conflict" in the generated parser, which is what the "answer" below is about. You also didn't specify to compile with std=c++17, nor with pthreads. It will not work without. Try something like ``g++ -std=c++17 *.cpp -pthread -DANTLR4CPP_STATIC -Igrammar -I......./antlr4/runtime/Cpp/runtime/src/ `find ....../antlr4/runtime/Cpp/runtime/src/ -name '*.cpp'` `` after `git clone` of antlr4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your syntax "rule" is a defined keyword, replace it to law and it will work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).